# Calling Java class in as3

Tags: java, actionscript-3

I'm trying to access Java from actionscript 3, so is it possible to call a Java class in actionscript 3? 
If it is then how?

Answer (score 1):

We need more information. Directly from flash, no. Is this a regular swf or an AIR app? Is it a java process running, or is it an applet on the same page? If it's a swf and an applet, it should be possible to bridge communications via javascript.

Comment: It is an AIR app. They are not on a webpage, It is a separate app.

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at [Flerry](http://www.riaspace.com/2010/01/flerry-flex-java-bridge-for-adobe-air-2-0/) which uses Air's [NativeProcess API](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/beta/reference/actionscript/3/flash/desktop/NativeProcess.html).

But I doubt that it will be possible to call Java from a non Air application because of flash player restrictions.

Comment: I'm using AIR. No I dont want to upload it in a webpage, I want it to be an separate application.

Comment: @user1167572 So you can use NativeProcess or the Flerry library based on it. Did you have a look at them?

Answer (score 0):

Actually there is an open source project which does just that.  I'll be damned if I can recall the name offhand though.

You might also take a look at http://www.gotoandplay.it/_articles/multiplayerCentral/tutorials/pro_javaInAS.php

But again - as these guys have correctly stated above - all we really can do is throw random shotgun tidbits of information at you without a more specific question.  What's you goal?  What do you want you app to do?  have you got some code you code post?

Comment: Well actually I want to make a simple messenger in AIR using the socket class. But the problem is that it wont work over the internet. it just worked on a local network. To make it work over the internet, I have to do port forwarding in the router but I dont want to do this. Java on the other hand can do port forwarding without accessing the router, thats wgy I want to use Java.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't mind going with .NET - I heard someone say good things about WebORB.NET integration server.  Wish I could be of more help Java wise.